# Db2 Console does not load in IBM cloud

Tags: sql, console, db2, ibm-cloud

This is the error message displayed when clicking on Open Console button in Resources under IBM Cloud

```
{"trace":"afa2173194440e7eb46925133c01adc9","errors":[{"code":"authentication_failure","message":"HWCSEC0005E: Check role failed,Unauthorized Access! Authentication pass but the login user is configured neither as administrator nor user role.","target":{"type":"","name":""},"more_info":""}]}
```

Have tried things like logging out and logging in, opening the cloud account in incognito mode, deleting temp files yet the console does not load. Any help is appreciated as this issue is preventing me from SQL lab practice

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a temporary issue whereby single sign-on from the https://cloud.ibm.com console is not able to validate the user properly in some situations. Unless this is already resolved, as a workaround you can go to the URL for your service instance and login directly.

From the Db2 Service Instance select "Service Credentials" and then "New Credentials" to create them if you haven't generated them before. In the resulting service credentials that are generated you will see the "https_url" field that you can use to login to directly. You can also use the provided username and password or your IBMid credentials may work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete your db2 instance and recreate another one in another location (especially if you used London, try Dallas for example).

Keep me in touch.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with London location. Deleted and created new service with Dallas as location and it worked perfectly