# Db2 Console does not load in IBM cloud - authentication failure error

Tags: sql, console, db2, ibm-cloud

[Db2 Console does not load in IBM cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62003466/db2-console-does-not-load-in-ibm-cloud)

I am having the same issue as the user above. I am using the Dallas location as it is the only location in North America with a Lite option. I have tried deleting the db2 instance and recreating, but I am receiving the same error message.

From the Db2 Service Credentials page, I have also tried navigating to the "https_url" directly instead of clicking Open Console. I use the username and password from the Service Credentials to login. The console loads, but it eventually gives an error:
HWCSEC0009E: Failed to call state restful api.
When I click on the menu icon on the top left, nothing appears.

Comment: operational problems with commercial websites are off-topic for stackoverflow, which is for programming questions.  Open a ticket with your cloud provider.  This is not a matter for stackoverflow.

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/unifiedsupport/supportcenter

IBM links to Stack Overflow on their Support Center page

The user to the link I provided was helped on here. I don't see why my case is different.

I have opened a ticket with IBM Cloud support. I have heard nothing from them so far, which is why I posted here.

Comment: as mentioned, only ibm can resolve problems with ibm hosted websites. there's nothing that stackoverflow readers can do to help with that. You get what you pay for...